# How to add white space before an element's border using CSS

Tags: html, css

My work required a small space just before the left red border (image attached for reference). How can I achieve this?

My code is below. (Please see a close look at the red border and the space between the black thin border. And the red thick border is the one I want to achieve; I don’t want *margin-left*. It is the space inside the div.)

```
<p style="width:350px;height:200px;border-left:3px solid red;background-color:grey;">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a pseudo-element with position `absolute` instead of a border for the red line. Then you should also add some `padding-left` or `text-indent` to the `p` element.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:350px;height:200px;background-color:grey;">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a linear gradient instead

```css
p {
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding-left: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,
  transparent 3px, red 3px,
  red 6px, transparent 6px
  );
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:350px;height:200px">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

Comment: yes better than pseudo-element but I will do it in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/omq14Ljd/

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your `p` element by a `div` with a `padding-left` :

```html
<div style="padding-left:5px;background-color:grey;border:1px solid #000;">
<p style="width:350px;height:200px;border-left:3px solid red;margin:0px">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
p:before{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    content: "";
    width: 5px;
    border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:350px;height:200px;margin-left:5px;border-left:3px solid red;background-color:grey;position:relative">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```